# Laravel Testing - migrating/refreshing wrong environment

Tags: php, laravel, testing

Laravel v5.5.14
PHPUnit v6.4.1

I have a Laravel application with a number of feature tests. My base `TestCase` uses the `RefreshDatabase` trait for triggering a DB refresh before each test, and the env variables in my `phpunit.xml` looks like so;

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
</php>
```

The intention being to leave the development `mysql` DB connection alone and run the tests using sqlite in memory. Despite these settings (and clearing cached config etc) the DB refresh always refreshes the `mysql` connection DB.

I've looked into the functionality within `RefreshDatabase` and debugged the `refreshDatabase` method, which contians;

```
$this->usingInMemoryDatabase()
                        ? $this->refreshInMemoryDatabase()
                        : $this->refreshTestDatabase();
```

And `usingInMemoryDatabase` always returns false. Looking at the content of that method, when retrieving the `DB_CONNECTION` from `config` it always returns `mysql`, even though it should be being overridden by the env variable above.

What is going on here?

Comment: Maybe the configuration is cached? Try deleting `/bootstrap/cache/config.php` if it exists.

Comment: What happens if you set this database in `.env` file? Maybe config from `phpunit.xml` is not used? Are you running this test manually or maybe via some CI for example Jenkins?

Comment: This is probably because you have `DB_CONNECTION` set in your shell environment. PHPUnit will not override those variables by default, but you can force override them https://stackoverflow.com/a/43717277/4233593

Answer (score 4):

Run `php artisan config:clear` before running the tests to clear the cache to make sure the config variables are not cached from a wrong environment. If this doesn't help run PHPUnit using your IDE (e.g PHPStorm) and specifically select your project `phpunit.xml`

[image]

Comment: That was it in my case. I had run `config:cache` before and I was almost going crazy because I was changing configuration and it didn't have any effect. Thanks!